# How can I get out of a team celebration happening during work hours and an hours drive away?

Tags: communication

The hospital where I work was recently "taken over" by a larger, more profitable facility. Consequently, myself and one co-worker are now part of a much larger team. However, those other team members are spread out, the closest being at least an hour drive away, depending on traffic. Our new manager would like to have a "celebration" for our career national recognition week, however, we would be required to drive to another facility, at least an hour away, which doesn't make it much of a celebration. How can we tactfully get out of attending without being labelled uncooperative? FYI, this is a difficult manager, we don't know the others on the team and won't have a need to, and we have already been to the larger facility at least twice, but other team members have never been to ours, we are monitored for productivity, and this will most definitely take away from that.

Comment: If this is happening during work hours, does that mean you can count the drive and the party as part of your work hours for the day?

Comment: Can you expense the miles?

Comment: Have you let your manager know that this celebration will take way from your productivity?

Comment: I'd suspect that going will be seen as more important than lost productivity but you might as well clear that up first.

Answer (score 8):

Hate to say it, but if you want to be a "team player", you may just have to suck it up and go.

Having said that, if there is any reason to be "busy" during the time, maybe putting out some kind of fire so you have to stay at the home office, that's an option.  Maybe you are too busy to go and just have to make the deadline.

Maybe you have car trouble...but then your bluff may be called and you may have to ride with said manager.    Maybe you call in sick, but it will appear you're just trying to dodge it.

There are all sorts of excuses to use, but ultimately, if you don't go it may look bad.

Comment: I agree with Joe... on top of his comment, I urge care when suggesting lying as an option to someone on a public forum.. it may be a small, innocent lie in reality but who know how long this post will be visible and who will read it in another context... I do think this answer is sound enough outside of the third paragraph

Comment: Let me clarify:    I was not suggesting a person do that...but it was an option, albeit a bad one that has a huge potential to backfire.

Comment: No problem.. I ended up giving the answer a vote.. your actual suggestion was "suck it up and go" and I think that is pretty sound advice..In reality, Im not totally against "craft a decent excuse" either but, I just wanted to point out that you never know who will read this in the future and it's conceivable that it is a potential employer... I have first hand experience with a company that would kick an employee out if they were to even acknowledge that minor deception is worth considering.. Im probably a little extra paranoid since I can be personally identified here.. carry on!